# Where is Laravel 4's github project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Now that Laravel 4 is still in beta, where can I find Laravel 4's github project?

If you're downvoting me, let me explain, why I asked. Laravel 3 is currently (Februray 2013) the stable version and Laravel 4 is in beta. It used to be that each component was a separate project. Then this changed and they were merged (as far as I can remember). But just searching Google for `Laravel 4 github` still gives me the Laravel 3 repository. **So, now it's on you downvoters to explain why I've been downvoted.**

Comment: If you downvote (whoever it is), at least add a comment to tell me what I've done wrong!

Comment: upvoted you because it is a legitimate question. Not long ago before it was merged looking at the development branch of laravel/laravel on github would not have given us the source for L4. I guess it would have been the next minor version update for L3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it on the [develop](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop) branch.